# Starting Angular on Xampp

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am a front-end Designer proficient with HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, jQuery, but now to boost on my career want to go on with **Angular.js**. I want to practise it on Xampp but am unable to understand how to start. I want to start up with a dummy site on "***Hotel Management Website***" for a hotel "ABC".

I have worked on Angular JS to know concepts of Directives, Services, Filters, Controllers, etc. at a beginner stage. I would be glad if someone could direct me to start up trying a dummy site on "**Xampp**", before I gain confidence to work it out in Real World Industry.

***About Website:*** The site must be able to add new people, assign them rooms, check out, have invoice, and take the feedback of the customers.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that Angular.js is only running on client side it's not mandatory to have a webserver (or an emulator like you XAMPP) running. You can even start with providing e.g. a static JSON file to fill you site with data.

If you want to jump in to both sides (server and client) I would start with e.g. a simple PHP script providing the JSON (e.g. based on a POST request) on the server. For the client side you find several examples how to fill the data provided by the JSON into a html page on the Angular website.

All the required changes you describe in the question (add new people, assign them rooms...) would happen on the server side then. The only thing Angular is for is to fill the page with the updated data based on the new generated JSON.

Comment: That helped a lot brother. You really explained it pretty efficiently. Sure, I can get data with a static json, but I would like to take dynamic real time data, for that I wanted to use Xamp as server, but for practise, you are right. I might try do it with static json files. Thnx for your answer. Or rather I might make a folder in htdocs in 'xampp' and start up there. I think that would be a good start. Later, I might use php to fill up form save and return data as dynamic json to my Angular files. ;)